# What is the current status of Web Speech API's Recognition on Firefox / Gecko?

Tags: firefox, browser, cross-browser, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

The [Web Speech API](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/)'s Speech Recognition functionality is implemented in some major browers (major Chromium-based ones like Chrome and Edge, as well as Webkit-based ones like Safari).

As of June 2023 / Firefox 114, the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API#browser_compatibility) lists "unsupported" for Firefox, and indeed trying to construct a `SpeechRecognition` object doesn't work, even with the special `media.webspeech.recognition.enable` flag listed in this [Mozilla blog entry](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/01/firefox-and-the-web-speech-api/) from 2016.

However, Firefox internal documentation seems to suggest the feature is in some way present. Looking through Firefox bugs and discussions, [bug 1248897](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1248897) seems to have been the major hub for the implementation of this feature from 2017 to 2021, with over 100 comments, many commits, and eventually a *"Status: RESOLVED FIXED"*.

- Does this status mean the feature is present in Firefox?
- If so, which version of Firefox? (does not seem to be the release version)
- If the feature has not been added to the release version, is it planned to be added, and is there a timeline?